# Dynamic export of variables ES5 to ES6

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, nuxt.js, es6-modules

I'm working on a vue/nuxt.js project and would like to apply the atomic design methodology, i would like to import the components in a clustered and smarter way.

currently

```
import ButtonStyled from '@/components/atoms/ButtonStyled.vue'
import TextLead from '@/components/atoms/TextLead.vue'
import InputSearch from '@/components/atoms/InputSearch.vue'
```

How I wish

```
import {
    ButtonStyled,
    TextLead,
    InputSearch
} from '@/components/atoms'
```

Solution?

`index.js` in folder of `atoms`

it works perfectly (ES5)

```
// ES5 works 
const req = require.context('.', false, /\.vue$/)

req.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  const componentName = fileName.replace(/^.+\/([^/]+)\.vue/, '$1')
  module.exports[componentName] = req(fileName).default
})
```

```
// ES6 does not work 
// ERROR: Module build failed, 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level
const req = require.context('.', false, /\.vue$/)

req.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  const componentName = fileName.replace(/^.+\/([^/]+)\.vue/, '$1')
  export const [componentName] = req(fileName).default
})
```

```
nuxt use ES6
```

`NOTE`: I can not export an object because I can not use `import {ButtonStyled}` or I will have to de-structure the object after importing it

I need to export so that I can use

```
import { ButtonStyled } from '@/components/atoms'
```

I need to export name of each component in the folder

Any advice, information or suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created a library that solved this problem for me, makes exports named from a directory and listens to the creation, rename and exclusion of the modules and updates the index.js that does the export.

### [named-exports](https://github.com/yungsilva19/named-exports)

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you need to be careful when making use of import/export on EM6, since now you can't export anywhere outside of the top level scope of the js file and the general treatment of it is different than in EM5.

Now with the problem. I see you are exporting the components from inside of a ForEach loop/function and that works totally fine in EM5 but with EM6 It's different, and at least I see two ways you can solve the problem if you aren't expecting the number of components to grow dinamically:

- Call a function that returns the component and export it, do it for each component. Should look something like this:

  ./componentsFile.js

  ```
  exports.component1 = () => { /*code...*/ return component }
  exports.component2 = () => { /*code...*/ return component }
  ```

  ./renderingFile.js

  ```
  import { component1, component2 } from './componentsFile.js'
  /* use the components that you get from the return... */
  ```
- The other way is to build an object which fields are the components. And destructure it when you are importing.

./componentsFile.js

```
     const component1 = /*Create the component*/
     const component2 = /*Create the component*/
     exports.object = {
         component1,
         component2,}
```

./renderingFile.js

```
   import { component1, component2 } from './componentsFile.js'
   /*Use the components...*/
```

I think you can get the idea with this two ways.

Comment: the fact is that I will work with hundreds of components, I can not export all manually, I need to export dynamically, in their examples, you have used fixed name of variables

Comment: @YungSilva: "I need to export dynamically"* There is no such thing as dynamic exports in ES6 modules. Why don't you write a simple script that generates such an "index" file?

Comment: @FelixKling honesemtane, i do not know how to do what you mentioned, I'm a beginner with javascript, could you help me with this?

Comment: @YungSilva: I would just write a simple shell script. Something like `ls  componens/ | sed 's#^\([^.]*\).*$#export {default as \1} from "@/components/atoms/&"#' > components/index.js`

Comment: @FelixKling: 
I was able to execute this command and generate an index.js file that exports all the components, but I have a problem, at each creation of a new component would I have to execute the command via command line on the terminal again? this would be very laborious, would be a cool way to run this command every time I generate application build, for this I would have to execute this command inside the javascript suggestion?

Comment: @FelixKling 
one problem with your code is that it is importing the index.js itself `export {default as index} from "@/components/atoms/index.js"`

Comment: @YungSilva: If your build process is written in JavaScript (Node.js) then you can do the same in node, e.g. using the [filesystem api](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), if that's easier. Filtering out the index file in the shell command is as easy as adding a  `grep -v index.js`

Comment: @FelixKling 

I was able to make the child_process of the node execute my file with this command, `ls components/atoms/ | sed 's#^\([^.]*\).*$#export {default as \1} from "@/components/atoms/&"#' > components/atoms/index.js` however it is still exporting index.js, could you show me that command without it exporting `index.js`?

Comment: @YungSilva `ls components/atoms/ | grep -v index.js | sed 's#^\([^.]*\).*$#export {default as \1} from "@/components/atoms/&"#' > components/atoms/index.js`

Comment: @FelixKling 
I have another problem now, is that this code needs to be executed before the build, do you have any idea how to make this code be executed before the application is built?